# WatchService is unreliable on Linux

Tags: java, watchservice

I've been trying a simple application of the WatchService in Java 7.  It watches a directory for new files.  It's running on Linux CentOS 6.  I can copy a file to the watched directory and I get the file create event.  All good.

I based this upon the Oracle sample.

The problem is that the key goes invalid inexplicably.  The Javadoc says there are several cases that can cause this, such as cancelling the key.  I'm not doing cancelling it.  It goes invalid while the program is running with no file creation happening.  Just sitting there and it goes invalid in minutes or longer.  One time it ran for four days before it mysteriously went invalid.

The only possible explanation from the Javadoc is that the watched directory is deleted or no longer available.  I'm certainly not deleting it.  That leaves availability.

Now I wonder if the Linux implementation that WatchService is using tells it that the directory is unavailable because of system load or something else.  I can't imagine what would do this.  The system isn't really loaded.  The filesystem containing the directory is local to this system.  The directory is not used by anything else.

What are some other possibilities?

Comment: Have you tried on another linux machine?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that can be used to reproduce the problem? Have you tried to use `inotifywait -m /path/to/directory` to compare the events observed by a native program with the events observed by your Java program?

Comment: Beware that inotify may not work well on all filesystems (e.g. overlayfs), in my experience `mount - o bind` on files where usually causing issues to how `LinuxWatchService` was working, because it enforces to register the parent folder for watching instead of the file. Other mount operation can cause different issues.